# Lang sub folder detection codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

In my lang load I would like to be able to try and make it so that if type admin then would pick up subfolder in admin and find the controller lang file. Same as what do with the glob.

How would that be possible for language load function?

> Unable to load the requested language file:
>   language/english/admin/*/dashboard_lang.php

```
$files = glob(FCPATH . 'application/modules/admin/controllers/*/*.php');

if ($files) {

foreach ($files as $file) {

$controller =  basename(strtolower($file), '.php');

$this->lang->load('admin/*'. $controller, 'english');

$data['controller_files'][] = array(
'controller' => $controller,
'install' => '',
'installed' => in_array($controller, $controller_files)
);

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this if you wanted to load a language file 
in a subfolder with the same name as the "controller".

**language/english/admin/dashboard/dashboard_lang.php**

```
$controller = '';

$path = FCPATH . 'application/modules/admin/controllers/*/*.php';

$files = glob($path, GLOB_BRACE);

if(!$files || empty($files)){
    log_message('error', "Unable to find any matches :  $path");           
}

foreach($files as $file){

    $basename   = basename(strtolower($file));

    $pathinfo   = pathinfo($basename);

    $controller = $pathinfo['filename'];

    $this->lang->load("admin/$controller/$controller", 'english');

    $data['controller_files'][] = array(
        'controller'    =>  $controller,
        'install'       =>  '',
        'installed'     =>  in_array($controller, $controller_files)
    );
}
```